# Why does my video from ffmpeg have a variable framerate?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, streaming

I tried stacking 4 3840x2160 mandelbrot sets into a 7680x4320 rectangle using ffmpeg built in filters directly (without producing the y4m as done below) and that produced a variable framerate video.

I speculated that perhaps ffmpeg was being too greedy and the filter was not fast enough, which was causing the variable framerate -- wild speculation I realize.

So, I tried another experiment, but I see the **same result** in which the output video has a **variable framerate** of around **25 to 27 fps** (I need a **constant framerate** specified for the container, 60fps):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -t 20 mandel.y4m

And then:

ffmpeg -i mandel.y4m 
-filter_complex 
"[0:v][0:v]hstack=inputs=2[top];
[0:v][0:v]hstack=inputs=2[bottom];
[top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2[out]" -map "[out]" 
-c:v libx265 -profile:v main -b:v 200M -minrate 200M -maxrate 200M -bufsize 400M 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -t 20 -y -pass 1 -an -f null /dev/null && 
ffmpeg -i mandel.y4m -filter_complex 
"[0:v][0:v]hstack=inputs=2[top];
[0:v][0:v]hstack=inputs=2[bottom];
[top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2[out]" -map "[out]" 
-c:v libx265 -profile:v main -b:v 200M -minrate 200M -maxrate 200M -bufsize 400M 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -t 20 -y -pass 2 mandel.mp4
```

EDIT:
The framerate is in fact constant.  But not 60 fps.  It's 24, for some reason.  Here is a simpler example with output:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[top];[2:v][3:v]hstack=inputs=2[bottom];[top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2[out]" -map "[out]" -c:v libx265 -profile:v main -b:v 200M -minrate 200M -maxrate 200M -bufsize 400M -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -t 20 -y 4MandelSyntheticWithStackFilters.mp4

or w/line breaks for clarity

ffmpeg 
-f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 
-f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 
-f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 
-f lavfi -i mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60 
-filter_complex 
"[0:v][1:v]hstack=inputs=2[top];
[2:v][3:v]hstack=inputs=2[bottom];
[top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2[out]" -map "[out]" 
-c:v libx265 -profile:v main -b:v 200M -minrate 200M -maxrate 200M
-bufsize 400M -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -t 20 -y
4MandelSyntheticWithStackFilters.mp4

ffmpeg version 5.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[0] / 0x424752), rgb0, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 tbr, 60 tbn
Input #1, lavfi, from 'mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[0] / 0x424752), rgb0, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 tbr, 60 tbn
Input #2, lavfi, from 'mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #2:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[0] / 0x424752), rgb0, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 tbr, 60 tbn
Input #3, lavfi, from 'mandelbrot=s=3840x2160:r=60':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #3:0: Video: rawvideo (RGB[0] / 0x424752), rgb0, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 tbr, 60 tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (rawvideo) -> hstack
  Stream #1:0 (rawvideo) -> hstack
  Stream #2:0 (rawvideo) -> hstack
  Stream #3:0 (rawvideo) -> hstack
  vstack:default -> Stream #0:0 (libx265)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 3.4+31-6722fce1f
x265 [info]: build info [Mac OS X][clang 12.0.0][64 bit] 8bit+10bit+12bit
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-6.1 (High tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 8 threads
x265 [info]: Slices                              : 1
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 3 / wpp(68 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias  : 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00 
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0
x265 [info]: References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : ABR-200000 kbps / 0.60
x265 [info]: VBV/HRD buffer / max-rate / init    : 400000 / 200000 / 0.750
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip mode=1 signhide tmvp
x265 [info]: tools: b-intra strong-intra-smoothing lslices=8 deblock sao
Output #0, mp4, to '4MandelSyntheticWithStackFilters.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 7680x4320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200000 kb/s, 60 fps, 15360 tbn
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx265
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 200000000/0/200000000 buffer size: 400000000 vbv_delay: N/A
frame= 1200 fps=1.0 q=41.7 Lsize=  500040kB time=00:00:19.95 bitrate=205329.2kbits/s speed=0.0163x        
video:500016kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:2kB muxing overhead: 0.004902%
x265 [info]: frame I:      5, Avg QP:26.50  kb/s: 964113.12
x265 [info]: frame P:    236, Avg QP:30.57  kb/s: 577628.54
x265 [info]: frame B:    959, Avg QP:38.13  kb/s: 109097.65
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 0.4% 0.0% 0.0% 0.4% 99.2% 

encoded 1200 frames in 1220.18s (0.98 fps), 204804.62 kb/s, Avg QP:36.60
```

Finally, note the framerate is not 60 fps, but instead 24.  Why is that?

```
ffmpeg -i 4MandelSyntheticWithStackFilters.mp4 -vf vfrdet -an -f null -
ffmpeg version 5.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
  libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
  libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
  libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
  libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
  libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
  libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '4MandelSyntheticWithStackFilters.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 204816 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 7680x4320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 204806 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 libx265
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf59.27.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p(tv, progressive), 7680x4320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.37.100 wrapped_avframe
frame= 1200 fps= 24 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:20.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.394x    
video:553kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_vfrdet_0 @ 0x7fdf00f27040] VFR:0.000000 (0/1199)
```

Comment: Could you simplify the command (just one pass for instance), and copy/paste the full terminal output (and possibly a ffprobe on the resulting file) ?

Comment: The issue in not reproducible. Please add the version of FFmpeg to your post.

Comment: @Rotem I did not correctly understand the issue.  The frame rate is 24 fps constant, but not the 60 fps requested (although this is set on the container).  One can see this in the 3rd to last line of the first edit "frame= 1200 fps= 24 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:20.00 bitrate=N/A speed=0.394x".  I'm using ffmpeg 5.1.  I'm contemplating including a nullsrc filter with a 60fps rate and overlaying the stacked videos on that to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Using a nullsrc filter as I described did not resolve the issue.  I still see 24 fps using the method in my previous comment.

Comment: I think `fps= 24` is the encoding rate (it's taking a long time to encode H.264 in high resolution). Try `384x216` resolution instead of `3840x2160`, and notice the value is above 60. Use FFprobe or MediaInfo tool for checking the framerate of the output video.

Comment: In the output of your latest command the video stream clearly appears as a 60fps one. I agree with @Rotem, the displayed 24fps looks like an encoding fps to pipe the streams to null. When you need to check a file, use ffprobe, not ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered in comments, but if you look at the "Output #0" sections, you can see that the video stream is marked as a 60 fps stream. The `fps= 24` section is a live-updating progress line.

NB If this is a log file, you won't see the console live-updating; in my console most of the time is spent updating that line:

```
frame=  556 fps=2.6 q=28.8 size=   15360kB time=00:00:03.84 bitrate=32765.6kbits/s speed=0.0182x
```

All of the fields in that line indicate the *current* encoding status, as of the last chunk (last few seconds, for me); as it appears in the final output, it's nearly meaningless, since it describes the last few seconds of encoding, rather than any kind of summary.